# Retrofit2 Ошибка Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Retrofit2 Ошибка Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?

**Запрос https://api.jeench.com/v1/search?query=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0&country_id=643&lat=55.76&lng=37.61**

Ответ JSON

```
{
  "13927": {
    "score": 1.7248458,
    "item_name": "Маникюр матовый",
    "item_data": "Маникюр ",
    "item_id": "13927",
    "group_data": "4669|Маникюр|2013|Ногтевой сервис",
    "group_id": "4669",
    "shop_id": "2635",
    "shop_name": "Маникюр \"Beautybar moscow\"",
    "item_price": 1300,
    "item_location": [
      {
        "lat": "55.72962190",
        "lon": "37.63292440"
      }
    ]
  },
  "15695": {
    "score": 1.7248458,
    "item_name": "Маникюр матовый",
    "item_data": "Маникюр ",
    "item_id": "15695",
    "group_data": "4669|Маникюр|2013|Ногтевой сервис",
    "group_id": "4669",
    "shop_id": "2823",
    "shop_name": "Маникюр \"Funky nails dinamo\"",
    "item_price": 1100,
    "item_location": [
      {
        "lat": "55.78537400",
        "lon": "37.55860800"
      }
    ]
  },...


public interface ApiSearch {
    @GET("/v1/search")
    Call<List<SearchGroup>> getData(@QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
}

public class SearchGroup {

    @SerializedName("item")
    @Expose
    private Search searches;

    public Search getSearches() {
        return searches;
    }

    public void setSearches(Search searches) {
        this.searches = searches;
    }
}

public class Search {

    @SerializedName("score")
    @Expose
    private double score;

    @SerializedName("item_name")
    @Expose
    private String item_name;

    @SerializedName("item_data")
    @Expose
    private String item_data;

    @SerializedName("item_id")
    @Expose
    private String item_id;

    @SerializedName("group_data")
    @Expose
    private String group_data;

    @SerializedName("group_id")
    @Expose
    private String group_id;

    @SerializedName("shop_id")
    @Expose
    private String shop_id;

    @SerializedName("shop_name")
    @Expose
    private String shop_name;

    @SerializedName("item_price")
    @Expose
    private double item_price;

    @SerializedName("item_location")
    @Expose
    private ItemLocation item_location;

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getItem_name() {
        return item_name;
    }

    public void setItem_name(String item_name) {
        this.item_name = item_name;
    }

    public String getItem_data() {
        return item_data;
    }

    public void setItem_data(String item_data) {
        this.item_data = item_data;
    }

    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public String getGroup_data() {
        return group_data;
    }

    public void setGroup_data(String group_data) {
        this.group_data = group_data;
    }

    public String getGroup_id() {
        return group_id;
    }

    public void setGroup_id(String group_id) {
        this.group_id = group_id;
    }

    public String getShop_id() {
        return shop_id;
    }

    public void setShop_id(String shop_id) {
        this.shop_id = shop_id;
    }

    public String getShop_name() {
        return shop_name;
    }

    public void setShop_name(String shop_name) {
        this.shop_name = shop_name;
    }

    public double getItem_price() {
        return item_price;
    }

    public void setItem_price(double item_price) {
        this.item_price = item_price;
    }

    public ItemLocation getItem_location() {
        return item_location;
    }

    public void setItem_location(ItemLocation item_location) {
        this.item_location = item_location;
    }
    }

public class ItemLocation {

    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("lon")
    @Expose
    private String lon;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}

searchList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("query", "сумка");
        parameters.put("country_id", "643");
        parameters.put("lat", "55.76");
        parameters.put("lng", "37.61");
        JeenchUser.getApiSearch().getData(parameters).enqueue(new Callback<List<SearchGroup>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SearchGroup>> call, Response<List<SearchGroup>> response) {
                searchList.addAll(response.body());

                for(int i=0;i<searchList.size();i++) {
                    Log.i("tester", "onResponse: "+searchList.get(i).getSearches().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SearchGroup>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during n

etworking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("tester", "error:   "+t.toString());
                   **/*ПОПАДАЮ В ЭТО ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ*/** 
                }
            });
```

Помогите пожалуйста правильно создать классы SearchGroup, Search
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот сайт для создания классов по JSON http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ Правда, похоже, что у вас в корне JSON ключи не заранее заданные значения, а значит вас ждёт боль и страдания с ручным парсингом.

Comment: Спасибо ЮрийСПб за сайт. Вы подтвердили мои опасения.